# Как проверить HTML5 textarea с помощью регулярного выражения ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Как проверить  **HTML5 textarea** с помощью регулярного выражения ?

Судя по всему в **HTML5 textarea** не поддерживает атрибут **pattern**.

Так как-же тогда проверить те символы, которые вводит пользовтаель?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21311717/6275986) (SOen).

Необходимо реализовать эту функцию самому:

```js
$('#test').keyup(validateTextarea);

function validateTextarea() {
    var errorMsg = "Please match the format requested.";
    var textarea = this;
    var pattern = new RegExp('^' + $(textarea).attr('pattern') + '$');
    // check each line of text
    $.each($(this).val().split("\n"), function () {
        // check if the line matches the pattern
        var hasError = !this.match(pattern);
        if (typeof textarea.setCustomValidity === 'function') {
            textarea.setCustomValidity(hasError ? errorMsg : '');
        } else {
            // Not supported by the browser, fallback to manual error display...
            $(textarea).toggleClass('error', !!hasError);
            $(textarea).toggleClass('ok', !hasError);
            if (hasError) {
                $(textarea).attr('title', errorMsg);
            } else {
                $(textarea).removeAttr('title');
            }
        }
        return !hasError;
    });
}
```

```css
:valid, .ok {
    color: green;
}
:invalid, .error {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
    <textarea name="test" pattern="[a-z]{1,30}(,[a-z]{1,30})*" id="test"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**P. S.** Код напильником подпилить нужно, но идею он показал.

**UPDATE**:

Для валидности `HTML5` нужно в оригинале заменить:

- **HTML**: `pattern="[a-z]{1,30}(,[a-z]{1,30})*"` -> `data-pattern="[a-z]{1,30}(,[a-z]{1,30})*"`.
- **JS**: `$(textarea).attr('pattern')` -> `$(textarea).data('pattern')`.

Comment: Так HTML код не будет валидный HTML5

Comment: В чём проблема - заменить атрибут `pattern` на `data-pattern` и всё будет отлично.

Comment: Велосипед на JavaScript.

Comment: @Khipster, можете предложить что-то лучше? Милости прошу.

Comment: @Other Я понял вашу мысль. Ну вообщем ровно то, что и сам придумал в течении одной минуты...Эх... Почему-же нету ничего более практичного. Спасибо.

Comment: @gilo1212, а что тут придумаешь? Либо дожидаться когда и `textarea` будет имплеменировать `pattern`, либо писать очевидный костыль.